# Pygame Scrolling Bug With Enemys

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with my enemy where when my player scrolls left the enemy scrolls with the player. Is there anyway to fix this?

[Video](https://gyazo.com/85ec003fe8b4b6277d3ae8698e376ee4)

My full code is linked below, as it's too long to fit here.

What I was trying to do is make my enemy not to change its position when my window is scrolling. Its doing the same for right and left and keeps following the player.

```
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False
  [...]
# I did the same for my players key movement  this part suppose to not make my player scroll
if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.y += playerman.speed
        for enemys in enemying:
            enemys.y += playerman.speed
```

My enemy class:

```
class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,end):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self.esright = [pygame.image.load("esright1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright3.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright4.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright5.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright6.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright7.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright8.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright9.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright10.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright11.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright12.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright13.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright14.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright15.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright16.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esright17.png"),
                          ]
        self.esleft = [pygame.image.load("esleft1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft3.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft4.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft5.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft6.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft7.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft8.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft9.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft10.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft11.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft12.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft13.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft14.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft15.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft16.png"),
        pygame.image.load("esleft17.png"),
                          ]
        self.esright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//3,image.get_height()//3)) for image in self.esright]
        self.esleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//3,image.get_height()//3)) for image in self.esleft]
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.distance = 80
        self.speed = 8
        self.vel = 3
        self.path = [x,end]
        self.walking_index = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
       def draw(self,window):
       self.move()
       if self.Walking_index + 1 >= 33:
           self.Walking_index = 0
       if self.vel > 0:
           window.blit(self.esright[self.Walking_index//3], (self.x,self.y))
           self.Walking_index += 1
       else:
           window.blit(self.esleft[self.Walking_index//3], (self.x,self.y))
           self.Walking_index += 1
       def move(self):
       if self.vel > 0:
           if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
               self.x += self.vel
           else:
               self.vel = self.vel * -1
               self.Walking_index = 0
       else:
           if self.x - self.vel >  self.path[0]:
               self.x += self.vel
           else:
               self.vel = self.vel * -1
               self.Walking_index = 0
```

Where I defined the enemy class:

```
black = (0,0,0)
enemys1 = enemy(550,436,50,50,300)
enemys = [enemys1]
```

My entire code is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/q2FvXxBc).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by how you draw the enemies. When you draw an object, you are using something like: `screen.blit(image, pos)` however, when you move, that `pos` variable does not update to compensate for the moving plane of view. Instead, do something like (this is pseudocode, so it wont work):

```
def onscroll(enemies_list, delta_scroll): # the delta_scroll variable is the change in 
#the screens location (positive or negative)
    for x in enemies_list:
        x.position = (x.position[0] - delta_scroll, x.position[1])
```

also, if you have a return position, you want to also compensate using:

```
x.return_pos -= delta_scroll
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wait I make a new def function? and  add for the x.return_pos -= delta_scroll I put it on my scrolling left right up?

Comment: I placed the scroll function in [my enemy class under it](https://gyazo.com/3cc3c4c91dbeb3fd5c9f7a9fa05a3a3e) and then called the x.return_pos -= delta_scroll  on my [Camera Movement For left and Right](https://gyazo.com/2817e5fcc9622a9ab33aebece19f6639) but I feel like I am doing something wrong  [I am getting this error](https://gyazo.com/fc65248d4cd5b36c2d5f720ea45756a0)idk what I am doing wrong

Comment: no, what I am saying is when, in your code you are moving the camera, you need to call this function for all enemies. This should move them to their correct positions in the camera’s view field

Comment: I am sorry if I am asking to much questions but I am fairly new to pygame could you show me how I could apply that to my code?

Comment: No worries, all you would need to do is add the function which I have provided to the main body of your code, and then call it when you update the screens position by running `onscroll(enemies, (<screens position> - <screens position last frame))` I am sorry if this is not clear enough, best wishes.

Comment: Also in answer to some of your previous comments, you need to place `x.return_pos -= delta_scroll` inside of the for loop. Sorry for not being very clear!

Comment: keeps saying function x is not defined.

Comment: for enemys in enemying:  I placed the onScroll function and then called it on my enemys 
            x.return_pos -= delta_scroll
            enemys.y -= playerman.fall

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet of the code you have edited and i will see what I can do.

Comment: [image1](https://gyazo.com/1998e981617745c2268e66f7daba07e5) [image2](https://gyazo.com/20eb5c02264d120dee9aac51d015ce27)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/ERuhgVzs here is the full code its easy to read basic stuff that I learned

Comment: ah yes, I see your issue - you are using the variable `deltascroll` to denote movement for enemies without calling the function. This can easily be fixed by replacing the `for enemys in enemying` line and all the code that goes with it with `onscroll(enemying, playerman.speed)` this should work.

Comment: `  x.position = (x.position[0] - delta_scroll, x.position[1])
AttributeError: 'enemys' object has no attribute 'position'` should I put the def scroll funtion in the enemy class?

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to mention - x.<position variable> is a placeholder and should not be used. Instead, substitute the <position variable> with the actual position variable - such as x.x

Comment: `        on.position = (x.position[0] - delta_scroll, x.position[1])
` I replaced it with on and I am getting this error 'enemys' object has no attribute 'position'

Comment: even tho I replaced it with all the position          def onscroll(enemies_list, delta_scroll):

    for on in enemies_list:
        on.position = (on.position[0] - delta_scroll, on.position[1])  I am gettting the same error 'enemys' object has no attribute 'position'

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d1ae4bb5fa8df5c68f4bd5599890fb26

Comment: yes, after checking all the code I realized there was an issue - use this code here and it should work (replace contents of the onscroll function with this): for on in enemy_list: on.y += delta_scroll. This code should 100% work.

Comment: like this? https://gyazo.com/995a0163ae22eab381a121506f45ffa3 this is what I did and it keeps saying  name 'delta_scroll' is not defined I replaced enemy_list with my enemying list for eeverything https://gyazo.com/fed405378e4fc9012473a65846dc63c1 sorry if I am giving you a hard time

Comment: Don’t worry - i’m sorry for not being very clear - all you need to do now is replace delta_scroll with playerman.fall